# Adding post values to database using mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I seem to have an issue inserting the post values into my database, and i don't see the error in the coding. I've been looking at it for a while now and to me everything looks right, however when i use the form and submit the data the page reload but no data get inserted into the database.

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me identify the error in the coding.

If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Kind regards Jim

**FORM**

```
<?php 

 //Show the form if the user is a Admin

 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   $username == $_SESSION['username'];

   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT authority FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
   while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
     $aut = $row->authority;
     }
  } 
  if($aut == 1){
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> &nbsp; Title: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top"> &nbsp; News: </td>
   <td><textarea name="information"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" value="news"> </td>
   <td><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
 </table> <hr>
</form>
```

**MYSQLI**

```
<?php
}

//Insert into the database

if(isset($_POST['news'])){
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $information = $_POST['information'];

 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO  `news` (`title`, `information`) VALUES ( '".$title."', '".$information."')");
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Anyway, check what is the value of `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: It's been fixed, the vulnerability will be dealt with as well. The form displays, so the username is not the issue.  <input type="hidden" value="news"> should be name, not value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="hidden" value="news">` should be `<input type="hidden" name="news">`

That's why `isset($_POST['news'])` will never be true.

Comment: Thanks mate, must have been staring myself blind, it's working as intended now! Such an easy error, hehe. You know what's up with the -1?

Answer (score 1):

Beside that silly typo problem your code suffers from two real disasters.

1. You have no error reporting, which renders you helpless against such silly mistakes
2. You are adding your data directly into query, while ought to use placeholders for that.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into this immediately.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what was intended with the backticks and periods in your original query.  In my limited experience my queries take the form of:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO news(title, information) VALUES ('$title', '$information')");
```

I would say that priority #1 is getting some debugging information in the form of return values for your php functions or access to php error logs.

Comment: It's as Mikayé said under. The backticks is for the database, as you say they are not needed in most occasions.